# I would like to know how to draw using canvas over my XML layout

Tags: android, xml

I've created a custom XML layout and I’m trying to draw the map background and the pawn player( the bitmap) over it.

Instead, its painting the pawn player over a white background without the map background that I put as the background on the XML file.

```
MyViev Class:

package com.example.alpha;


import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class MyView extends View {
    Bitmap playerW;
    float changingY;
    float changingX;
    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        playerW = BitmapFactory
                .decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.black);
        changingY=0;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawBitmap(playerW,4+changingX, (canvas.getHeight())-288-changingY, null);
    }

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

}

my MainActivity Class:

package com.example.alpha;


import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    MyView ourView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ourView = new MyView(this);
        setContentView(ourView);

    }
}

My XML file:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<view class="com.example.alpha.MyView"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/myView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/mapeasy"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're not actually setting it to use your XML layout. Instead, you've set the content View to be a new instance of MyView, which doesn't have the XML background property set.

Therefor you have 2 options:

**Option 1**: Call ourView.setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.mapeasy); after you created a new instance of MyView.

or

**Option 2**: Set the content View to be your actual layout file and then find your MyView by using findViewById(int).

Eg.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    MyView ourView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_file);
        ourView = (MyView)findViewById(R.id.myView);
    }
}
```